# Is it possible to support iPad multi tasking without size classes?

Tags: ios, ipad, split, multitasking

I have multiple apps that have been written a long time ago without size classes. Is it possible to support iOS iPad multitasking without size classes for the main screen? If so, any pointers on this?

How do I know when the user has split the screen in the landscape 50/50?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sure. You just need a launch screen file and your app needs to render properly no matter what size it is given.

Comment: maddy, thank you. I guess what I am asking is how do I know when the user has split the screen in the landscape 50/50?

Comment: Look at the docs for UIViewController. There are methods you override when the size changes and when the traits change. It's also covered in the View Controller Programming Guide.

Comment: Thanks. Should have looked at that a long time ago.